# Favorite questions in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

I haven't been able to find my favorite questions in the official Stack Exchange Android app.

Looking at my accounts page gives nothing on them.

Comment: I am reading this post in 2019 and sadly, the Android app still doesn't have the requested function.

Answer (score 25):

Currently this is really difficult to do in app, it definitely needs to be done in a better way. For now, you can search `infavorites:mine` on a site to get your favorites, but this obviously can be done better.

Comment: @ShadowWizard give it 6-8 weeks

Comment: Any update on when/if this is going to happen please?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I promise this is actually on my task list for this upcoming week (I angrily stared at this link in my TODO bookmarks folder 3x today due to it annoying me using the app myself)

Comment: Thanks! Really looking forward to having this on the app.

Comment: Is this still on the todo list ?

Comment: Does who develop the app? Maybe, (s)he needs community contributions of code? Is the app open/close-sourced?

Comment: This is still on the to do list. I'm talking about it in our team chat room right now. The functionality is easy to add in, I already have the code (it's just injecting `infavorites:229741` into the search bar) -- The harder part is figuring out where in the UI to put the button / if it should only be available when you already have some favorite questions (so we'd have to do the API call before showing it, etc) -- I really want to do this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard / all -- This is my current "what if?" mock-up, it works but requires a _LOT_ of testing before I can release it, it might go to beta if I can make sure it doesn't crash tablets too: http://i.imgur.com/A0pnUnV.png -- I'm not sure what we're going to add in that second nav, but "Favorites" will be there.

Comment: Sorry about the delay (both on the initial ignoring of this, and saying I was going to do it earlier last month but not getting around to it, I ended up being out of work for a week and a half due to an illness)

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe, the button might be placed in the left-side menu.

Comment: @SergeySarbash which left side menu? I'm currently considering what's in the picture I posted, which ads drop-down links after clicking on a specific site in the left sidebar (or if you open the sidebar while on a question / etc) -- I'm also considering instead taking out the Questions/Users/Tags drop down in the main Action Bar and moving that into a tab UI, like we have on iOS (and as of last I/O that's also an accepted part of material design)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi sorry for a dilettantism I meant sidebar of course. It might be placed below "Feed" menu. And there might be grouping of favorites, sorting etc. Ah, I can't find the pic You referred to.

Comment: I used this `infavorites:mine` in the Android app on a site where I have no favorites. It shows me the list of the highest upvotes (my guess) instead. Is that intended? Can I also get a list of my favorites for all of my sites?

Comment: @ott no, not via the app.

Comment: Any idea where to submit a feature request for this?

Comment: @MarcM. no point, this will never be done. The whole android app is one big sad joke. Year after the developer promised something, **NOTHING WAS DONE**. Not a single thing. Instead, they made whole NEW app, with exactly the same bugs and lack of any feature. Sad, right?