# How can I see all the favorites?

Tags: feature-request, questions, android-app, bookmarks

Where are all my favorite questions listed? I recently added one and I'll need to browse it later. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't specify that I'm on the android app, and following your link doesn't bring me to anything

Comment: I think that still isn't implemented yet. It was already asked in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229658/favorite-questions-in-the-android-app)

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer