# Easy/relevant way to see a post/fav in SE mobile apps

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

I am using SE mobile app on Android.

I could not find an easy way to see my posts, my favs unlike in website version of SE. Only way I could find is to browse my notifications, which is an indirect, irrelevant way to do just that.

Is there a direct and relevant way to see a post/fav in SE Android mobile app? Am I missing the point?

Comment: You are not missing anything, it's possible to see the favorite posts but they did not really bother to  make it easy.

Comment: No sir, the question linked above mine does not have an answer to my question. So, the decision of closing this question as duplicate is wrong here.

Comment: Yes it does: "you can search infavorites:mine on a site to get your favorites". If not, it means you failed to explain what you really want.

Comment: Let me point out that the question that is linked as duplicate does ask *finding favourite questions of the user in the SE Android app*, the above one is asking *finding **posts** and **favourites** of the user in the SE mobile app* by
>Is there a direct and relevant way to see a post/fav in SE Android mobile app?.
Also it is asking for the existence of a direct/relevant way of achieving this, but not an irrelevant way that exists as described in the question.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean. Probably language barrier. Good luck. (If you think it's not a duplicate, explain why by editing, then it will enter the Reopen review queue, and other users might understand what you mean and reopen it.)

Comment: @Pat in case you get the ping, please take a look on OP's comments, personally can't see how it explains why it's not a dupe, but if you can, you can also reopen.

Comment: The question of mine does not ask only for favourites it asks for posts and favourites. So it is not an exact duplicate as said in the flag under the question. For [handling duplicates](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/).

Comment: You can't ask two questions in one question, that's not how this site works. If you mean how to see your full list of posts, it's also already asked: [Where can I see my full list of Questions and Answers in my profile page of Stack Exchange Android App?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262284).

Comment: The two things in my question is very close to be count as an exception for asking only one thing in a question, if not then you failed to explain the problem with my question.And those who selected the exact duplicate to mine to be [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229658/favorite-questions-in-the-android-app) have also failed to select a duplicate to my question.The latter question you have sent to be exact duplicate in just above comment of yours is also lacking the *favourites* and have *answers* as excess which I have not asked for and **does ask two things**.